# Nahe bei vs in der Nähe

Tags: difference, preposition

> Ich lebe in der Nähe [von] der Universität Hamburg.
>
> Ich lebe nahe bei der Universität Hamburg.

Was ist der Unterschied? Haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung in diesem Kontext und warum?

Comment: Besser ist "Ich lebe nahe der Uni Hamburg". Wenn leben in der Universität ausgeschlossen wäre "Ich lebe bei der Universität" schon gleichbedeutend mit "nahe/in der Nähe" ("Ich lebe bei der Außenalster", ok/"Ich lebe bei meiner Mutter" nicht ok, versteht man als mit ihr zusammen, auch "Ich lebe beim Hotel Atlantik" (drinnen?)).

Answer (score 5):

Interessante Frage, denn im genannten Beispiel sehe ich keinen Unterschied, sehr wohl aber in den folgenden beiden Sätzen:

> Ich stehe in ihrer Nähe.
>
> Ich stehe nahe bei ihr.

In diesem Fall impliziert "nahe" meiner Meinung nach eine geringere Entfernung als "in ihrer Nähe".

Im Duden Bedeutungswörterbuch wird sowohl bei "nah/nahe" als auch bei "Nähe" als erstes auf die geographische Bedeutung und als zweites auf die Bedeutung im Kontext von Zeit eingegangen. Bei den Erläuterungen ist jeweils kein erkennbarer Unterschied auszumachen, aber bei "nah/nahe" gibt es noch eine 3. Bedeutung: "in enger, direkter Beziehung zu jemandem" und die gibt es bei "Nähe" nicht.

Das bedeutet: in dem von Dir genannten Beispiel gibt es laut Duden keinen erkennbaren Unterschied (bei *nah* steht "nicht weit entfernt, in kurzer Entfernung befindlich" und bei *Nähe* steht "geringe räumliche Entfernung"). (Aus dem Bauch heraus würde ich trotzdem sagen, dass "nahe bei" irgendwie näher klingt als "in der Nähe" von)

Die zweite Frage ist: warum?
Ich finde es nicht weiter erstaunlich, dass nahe und Nähe die gleiche Bedeutung haben. Viel spannender finde ich, dass es in Bezug auf Personen eine Abweichung gibt: "Ich bin Dir gern nahe" ist nicht das gleiche wie "Ich bin gerne in Deiner Nähe".

Comment: To me, "nahe der Uni" is closer to the university than "in der Nähe der Uni". "Nahe" is maybe 500 m, while "in der Nähe" could be 2 km or more. "Nahe" is synonymous to "in Fußweite", while "in der Nähe" is relative to the size of the city and takes into account all modes of transportation.